# Why do we need a web server along side an app server in an orchestrated containerised architecture?

Tags: nginx, flask, containers, api-gateway, orchestration

Assuming I am using framework like Flask to serve requests, I understand that web server handles static file requests and directs any program execution requests to the app server. Example: nginx. Where as app server can handle both static files as well as program executions. Example: gunicorn.

It makes sense to have a web server to handle static files, caching, request redirection, load balancing. The request first comes to the web server and it knows how to handle it and redirect any program executions to the app server.

However, in architectures where we use orchestration and containerization, that is - there is cluster of nodes, each node running a container - assume the container has got only the app server (example: gunicorn), and the request arrives at the API management/gateway(which has same features as a web server - other than serving static files), gets redirected  to the cluster of nodes (which does load balancing), eventually the request reaches a node containing the appserver (example: gunicorn) that serves the request.

Is there any benefit of having a web server running along side an app server inside such a configuration?

In azure does API gateway play the role of webserver equivalant?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. It's common to have some proxy / routing logic (e.g. url rewrite) in the API Gateway, so probably this is why you can have the app server and the web server inside a container.

In Azure, API Management is a fully managed API Gateway which allows you to implement caching, routing, security, api versioning, and more.

More info:

https://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern

Comment: What you mean by "both" in your answer?

Comment: You have not mentioned what is the use of having a web server running along side an app server inside the container instead of having only the app server?

Comment: If you need proxy / routing logic (e.g. url rewrite), you'll find app server and web server running inside the container. Another alternative, is an external tool as you've mentioned API Management on Azure.

Comment: You mean that - if the proxy/routing bit is handled by the API gateway, then there is no need of web server inside the container (only app server is sufficient). Where as if there is no API gateway, then we need web server inside the container (to configure proxy/routing), along with the app server. Right?

Comment: you'll always need API Gateway. You can move some things to a sidecar pattern (service mesh) or leave it in the API Gateway. There's no right or wrong ...depends on your scenario, features available in your API Gateway, cost, many factors..

Comment: in summary ..if you API Gateway implements all features you need, no need for web and app server inside the container

Comment: App server is needed. Otherwise how will the website run inside the container?